# Static methods requiring var

Tags: php, static

Ok, i'm stuck on this, why don't i get what i need?

```
class config
{

    private $config;

    # Load configurations
    public function __construct()
    {
        loadConfig('site'); // load a file with $cf in it
        loadConfig('database'); // load another file with $cf in it
        $this->config = $cf; // $cf is an array
        unset($cf);
    }

    # Get a configuration
    public static function get($tag, $name)
    {
        return $this->config[$tag][$name];
    }
}
```

I'm getting this:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in [this file] on line 22 [return $this->config[$tag][$name];]
```

And i need to call the method in this way: `config::get()`...

Comment: static functions are called in the context of the class, and don't have a reference to any particular instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`public static function get`

need to be

`public function get`

You can't use `$this` in static methods.

**EDITED**

I could do this, but I'm not sure if it's the best design for you.

```
class config
{

    static private $config = null;

    # Load configurations
    private static function loadConfig()
    {
        if(null === self::$config)
        {
            loadConfig('site'); // load a file with $cf in it
            loadConfig('database'); // load another file with $cf in it
            self::$config = $cf; // $cf is an array
        }
    }

    # Get a configuration
    public static function get($tag, $name)
    {
        self::loadConfig();
        return self::$config[$tag][$name];
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to call the method get() as config::get() without the instance.

Comment: Then the $config property need to be static and, in this case, you can't have a constructor. See this example http://code.google.com/p/simple-php-framework/source/browse/trunk/includes/class.config.php?spec=svn199&r=199

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're **`Using $this when not in object context`**... Declaring a method as static removes the possibility to use the `$this`-reference inside the method.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `$this` reference inside static methods as they belong to the class. Static methods can only access static members, so if it is important that `get()` is a static method, make `$this->config` a static member and `return self::$config[$tag][$name]`. However, the static keyword makes methods accessible without an instance of the class and I'd advise either making `get()` non-static, or making the class a singleton (depending on how you wish to use it).